# How do you specify where to output the executable in a Cabal file?

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

Is there a way to customize the directory that the compiled executable `cabal install` makes gets saved to?

I've looked at http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/ for this information but am having a hard time finding it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `cabal build` is putting stuff into `dist/build/`, not `cabal install`.

Comment: You're right. cabal install puts the executable on my PATH. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use a different installation path for a particular invocation of `cabal install`, as **melpomene** said, you can use the command-line options described at http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/installing-packages.html#installation-paths

If you want to change where `cabal install` puts things as a *general rule* (rather than just modifying the location for a specific package), see your `~/.cabal/config` file specifies where everything goes. In the `install-dirs user` section, look for the `prefix`, `bindir` and `libdir` settings. The default settings are commented out. Modify those as needed.